# Simple conversion of SQL date field to mm/dd/yyy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem converting three columns to mm/dd/yyyy format in MS SQL Server.

There are a number of methods I've looked up here but nothing that quite worked when I tried to implement it. It's a very basic set of columns I'm pulling.

```
SELECT 
[Incident_Number] 
,[Corporate_ID]
,[Assignee_Login_ID]
,select *, cast ([Submit_Date] as date) <TIME_CREATED> from SERVICEMGMT where date = 'mm/dd/yyyy' 
,[Last_Resolved_Date] as TIME_RESOLVED
,[Closed_Date] as TIME_CLOSED
,[Description]
 FROM [SERVICEMGMT].[dbo].[Help_Desk]
Where (corporate_id LIKE ('b%') AND TEMPLATE_NAME =  ('PC: Local Build/Deployment') AND STATUS > 3);
```

I'm getting a basic incorrect syntax error. The actual error messages are:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you ask a question about SQL, please include the tag for the DBMS you're using.  It looks like it might be MS SQL Server or Sybase.  The trouble is that different DBMS have different ways of handling things, especially time-related functionality.  The square-bracket notation you're using is not standard SQL, for example.  (The SQL standard didn't standardize time until long after many of the DBMS had provided some date/time functionality already, and backwards compatibility becomes an issue.)

Comment: You're probably getting your syntax error from `<TIME_CREATED>`; that should be an identifier, not malformed comparisons.  Use `[TIME_CREATED]` or `"TIME_CREATED"` there, probably.

Comment: You have two `select`s. It's not clear what you want from the "TIME_CREATED" one: Scalar subqueries need to be in parentheses and can only return a single column and row. I'm guessing that you need an inner join there (or a correlated subquery.)

Comment: Also please post the actual error message otherwise we have to guess what it is. It would be helpful if you posted a minimal DDL as well. Make it easy for people to help you - if you want them to help you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. To answer your questions it is MS SQL Server for DBMS. The brackets I got right clicking my table and running the Select top 1000 rows query.

Shawn - I tried to changing the syntax as per your suggestion and GMc as per your request here's my actual error message:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: If you want a sub-select in the select-list of the main query, you would need to enclose it in parentheses — `, (SELECT *, CAST([Submit_Date] AS date) <TIME_CREATED> from SERVICEMGMT where date = 'mm/dd/yyyy')`, but you may not be able to select multiple columns like that.  It is not clear to me what that secondary SELECT is meant to be doing — but you aren't meant to do it like that.

Comment: Hi Jonathan if you're saying that second select doesn't belong I'll definitely defer to you. I tried putting in your code got a couple of other errors. One of which it's looking at that second to last date before the = as an incorrect column. I tried to clean it up as best I could, I put in the below query and got the below error.

Comment: SELECT 
[Incident_Number] 
,[Corporate_ID]
,[Assignee_Login_ID]
,(SELECT *, CAST([Submit_Date] AS date) [TIME_CREATED] FROM [SERVICEMGMT].[dbo].[HPD_Help_Desk] where [Submit_Date] = 'mm/dd/yyyy')
,[Last_Resolved_Date] as TIME_RESOLVED
,[Closed_Date] as TIME_CLOSED
,[Description]
FROM [SERVICEMGMT].[dbo].[HPD_Help_Desk]
Where (corporate_id LIKE ('b%') AND Z1D_TEMPLATE_NAME =  ('PC: Local Build/Deployment') AND STATUS > 3);

Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 5
Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.